# c++ why this error "basic_string::substr" and breaking up the loop

Tags: c++, function, vector, substr

i am trying to get the last letters of a word, to compare if these letters row are in a vector. 
So i want to check first the last 2, then the last 3 and the last 4 letters. As soon as it finds one, it should break up, and return false. Else it should check everything left, and return in case of nothing founded, true.

This my function:

```
bool isIt(wstring word, vector <wstring> vec) {

int ct = 2;
while (ct < 5) {
    word = word.substr(word.length() - ct, word.length()-1);
    //wcout << word << endl;
    if (find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), word) != vec.end()) {
        //wcout << "false" << endl;
        ct = 5; return false;

    } else {ct++; wcout << ct << endl; continue; }
}  return true;}
```

the function get called thru this:

```
if( word >3){ isIt(word, vec); }
```

when the first check does fail, i receive this error msg:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>     what():  basic_string::substr

i don't understand, why it does not continue, once it is in the else part. 
I hope my description was good enough. 
BR

Comment: Comparing `wstring` and `string` might not always work. You should settle for one.

Comment: Assigning 5 to `ct` just before returning won't do anything but make people wonder why it's being assigned a value, and that one in particular, if it's just going to be discarded.

Comment: `word = word.substr(word.length() - ct, word.length()-1);` here you assign your cut down word to itself. Next run you try to substr the already short string... This cannot work...

Comment: ah sorry, yes, this was a mistake here, i copy the code, and change the function head, to make it short. I actually had: vector <wstring> .. there is another mistake, which cause this error msg :)
@RedX: this should be fine or? first ct=2, but when it should be 3 it breaks up, although the word is big enough :S

Comment: What is `word.length() - ct` when `word` is `"ABC"` and `ct` is `4`?

Comment: @Chris: i wanted to be sure, that it get out the while loop

Comment: @Drew Dormann oh before it goes to this function, i made an if statement to be sure that the word is bigger than 3. so it should be works?

Comment: @RamisHabib No. RedX already commented why.

Comment: @Drew Dormann e.g. the word is: "dkeiur" .. then the sub str makes "ur", and since its not in the vector, it goes in the else part, and then it breaks up. Why it doesn't start again, and make the substr with ct= 3?

Comment: You just added `if( word >3)`.  If `word` is a `wstring`, I'm positive that's not your real code.

Comment: @Drew Dormann no the problem was that it overwrite itselfs, as u wrote or?  .. yes word was a wstring too  .. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is here, where you modify `word`.

```
    word = word.substr(word.length() - ct, word.length()-1);
```

If `word` is `"ABCD"` entering this function then the first time through the loop this evaluates to:

```
    word = std::string("ABCD").substr( 2, 3 );
```

And the second time through your loop it evaluates to:

```
    word = std::string("CD").substr( size_t(-1), 1 );
```

Comment: oh yes thanks a lot. I changed it to :
word1 = word.substr(word.length() - ct, word.length()-1);
now it works i think :)